# containing div with max-height having a contained div that do not overflow using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following html.

The height of div B is set using max-height.  It contains 2 divs, B1 and B2 that have a variable heights.

When the height of B1+B2 is smaller than the height of B, I want B1 and B2 to have their normal height (and the height ob B to be smaller than it's max-height).  This part is working.

When the height of B1+B2 is higher than the one of B, I don't want B2 to overflow the div B (I want the bottom of B2 to match the bottom of B, and the content inside B2 to overflow B2).  **How can I achieve this?**

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHFBv/9/) for a better understanding.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
        <div id="B1">D1</div>
        <div id="B2">
            D2 - long content
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line                
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line               
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
            <br/>line
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: Ryan, I edited the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change css of b2 to :

```
#B2 {
    position:absolute;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    max-height:inherit;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

I know it's not perfect because the max possible height of b1 + b2 will be b+b1, but maybe this could be acceptable in your case ?

Comment: I tried your code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6469p/1/).  It does not seems to work (B2 keeps it's full height, like if there was no max-height).

Comment: strange, i did test it on jsfiddle.  i'll try to reproduce it and will send you the link maybe this weekend

Comment: You forgot the position:absolute :)    see [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6469p/3/)